# Низкий фпс из-за Semaphore.WaitForSignal

Tags: c#, unity3d

Низкий фпс в игре на андроид, в Profiler показывает, что всё сжирает Semaphore.WaitForSignal. Как можно решить данную проблему?

vsync выключен, фпс ограничен с помощью Application.targetFrameRate = 60;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semaphore.WaitForSignal - это метод, который "ждёт" пока видеокарта не закончит свои вычисления.

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то проблема в маленьком fps.
Судя по данным на скриншоте видеокарта вашего устройства не способна выдать 60 кадров в секунду.
Упростить графику, после чего попробуйте замерить снова.

Comment: Да это помогло, не думал, что GPU мобильных устройств такие слабенькие